# Changing the blog template to new template

Tags: blogger, website

I have a blog based on the installed free designed template. It works absolutely fine but now I want to replace the old design template with NEW TEMPLATE. Problem here is when I installed it both the designs old and new were mixed up.

How can I solve this?

Do I have to do any more changes or anything?

Answer (score 1):

In your Dashboard, under Themes > Customise, you can choose a new template.

Do this and then click the Remove Customizations link - shown here:

[image]

Also, click Edit (to else the Theme) and click Revert Widget Themes - as shown here:

[image]

We cannot be any more specific than that without knowing your blog's URL and a precise description of what is happening to make you think that the themes are getting mixed up.